# Best practice of c/C++ dependency management on build servers?

Tags: c++, c, builds, dependency-management

I develop largely in java which has maven or ant/ivy. Is there a recommended way to manage build dependencies for c++ projects? I'm setting up the build on our build server right now but the thing that comes to mind is that if the dependency libraries change how do I track that so old builds are not affected but new ones can use newer versions of a library?

One simple thought is that I move all the third party libraries into my repository and then reference them with:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "mosquitto.h"
```

Instead of

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>
```

Can someone recommend how to best do this in production?

Comment: Definitely don't change the code. Moving 3rd party libraries into your repository is fine, but change the _include path_ to accommodate them.

Comment: @AlexReinking when you say don't change the code, that means keep the "<sqlite3.h>?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @AlexReinking May I ask how you normally organize third party libraries in a repo? Do you just stick the components into a directory called thirdparty at the root of the repo or is there a more ideal naming convention that is normally used?

Comment: If you look at my answer, that's what I suggest. I prefer `third_party`, but I've also seen `thirdparty`, `Ext`, `deps`, and others.

Comment: > move all the third party libraries into my repository 

You can use `git submodule` or `git subtree` to incorporate specific versions of an external dependency into your repository (assuming `git` of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving third party build dependencies into your repository is perfectly fine, and even has some advantages (eg. no version mismatches, tracked upgrades). But doing so should not touch your code.

C/C++ use an [*include path*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) to determine where to find libraries that are included like so

```
#include <...>
```

Depending on your toolchain and build system, you'll have to follow different steps to configure this. Regardless, the best thing would be to create a "third_party" folder with subfolders containing each dependency. Then add each of *those* folders to your include path such that your existing include directives work.

In CMake, you should use the `target_include_directories` to accomplish this. In a plain Makefile with GCC or clang, you would add the `-I` flag for each folder.

Comment: If I could inquire just a little more, inside the third_party do you normally place the sqlite.h files at the root of the subdirectories "sqlite3" or "mosquitto" or is there an extra level of directories for "include" and "lib/x86_64-linux-gnu". Seems to me just the first level is sufficient?